# Cloudbees SDK Installation failure for Eclipse Indigo SR2

Tags: eclipse, git, plugins, sdk, cloudbees

Working with the SDK from my command line in my linux box is ok. 
But know I want to use the provided plugin for Eclipse. I have Eclipse Indigo version SR2 Build id: `20120216-1857`. 
I have installed egit scm version 1.3.0.2 with jgit. 
I use the following link as installation path:
http://eclipse.cloudbees.com for the cloudbees plugin. 
Take into account that the latest version of e-git doesn't work with Eclipse Indigo. So I installed egit from the following supported version link:http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-1.3. So I fire up the install software for cloudbees and while it tries to discover dependencies,it cannot install the plugin because of :

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: CloudBees Toolkit
>   2.0.2.201307232010 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.feature.group 2.0.2.201307232010)   Missing requirement: CloudBees SCM Egit 2.0.2.201307232010 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.dev.scm.egit 2.0.2.201307232010) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jgit 2.3.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: CloudBees Toolkit 2.0.2.201307232010 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.feature.group 2.0.2.201307232010)
>       To: com.cloudbees.eclipse.dev.scm.egit [2.0.2.201307232010]

Clearly I can't because there is a failure in versions required of egit for cloudbees plugin to work. The problem is that the egit plugin I have is different from the one required.So the two possibilities are:

- Somehow install version 2.0.2 of Egit..which I don't think is the case.
- Did someone tested correctly the versions of supported egit in indigo sr2 and cloudbees sdk?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message you need EGit version 2.3.0 or later.

EGit 2.3.0 works fine with Eclipse Indigo SR2 and with the latest CloudBees Toolkit.

"2.0.2" from the error message is the CloudBees Toolkit version.

EGit 2.3.x is supported by Eclipse Indigo SR2 as long as EGit Import Support is not installed. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F for the list of supported EGit versions for a specific Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

I discover the solution...the problem is that if you decide to install following installations from market place it will fail, because the version of egit 3.2 isn't supported by eclipse indigo sr2 specially the functionality Import Source cause the eclipse to crash. The way to install Cloudbees plugin in indigo is simple.

Use the following link to install Egit:http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.3
In the plugins to be included only add Egit and JGit basic functionality. Install and restart.
Afterwards through the market place install cloudbees eclipse plugin.Est voila. The problem comes not from Cloudbees itself but throw an indirect dependency failing.

regards
\n\m